# create fn for chenge CSS style in js

Tags: javascript, css, function, queryselector

I need to create a function for changing the CSS Style like the below:
(because I use this several times in my code)

```
document.querySelector('.number').style.width = '30rem';
document.querySelector('.number').style.color = 'green';
document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

can use like displayStyleNumber function:

```
const displayStyleNumber = (classElement, property, value) => {
  const displayCssStyle = `document.querySelector('${classElement}').style.${property} = '${value}';`
  return displayCssStyle;
}
```

when I use it, doesn't work!!!
which part is wrong?

Comment: You are creating a string and returning this string. Why would it execute this string as a javascript code?

Comment: Use CSS classes, then add and remove the classes as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean?:

```js
const displayStyleNumber = (classElement, property, value) => {
  document.querySelector(classElement).style[property] = value;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="displayStyleNumber('#btn', 'backgroundColor', 'red')">click me</button>
```

In your current form, the code creates a string and then returns it, it won't execute it

Also, name of this function is misleading

Comment: that's right. I got it. thanks.